# 0 Records exist Alteryx, even though data exists

Tags: alteryx

I have a couple of excel files I want to load into Alteryx,

I can see in the preview that records exist, when I run the flow it says 0 records displayed, as below

Any ideas?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: You should be able to see the number of rows processed by each tool in the workflow, in order to pinpoint where some condition failed and data flow stopped. My guess would be at the Join, but that's just a guess.

Comment: It hasent failed after any processing, as shown in the screenshot, this is the output records I'm getting at the start, just loading it into Alteryx, it seems that there are records there, but its showing 0 displayed